# How to get pending transactions on BSC

Tags: websocket, web3js, binance

I am trying to get pending transactions from the mempool on BSC using a websocket - the same way I was getting pending transactions on the Ethereum network:

```
web3Ws = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(WEBSOCKET_PROVIDER_LINK));
web3Ws.eth.subscribe('pendingTransactions', function (error, result)
```

When working with Ethereum, I set `WEBSOCKET_PROVIDER_LINK` to be `wss://${NETWORK}.infura.io/ws/v3/${PROJECT_ID}`, but I don't know how to create WebSocket to get pending transactions on BSC.

What provider link can I use to get pending transactions on BSC?

Comment: What provider are you using in `WEBSOCKET_PROVIDER_LINK`? (Censor any sensitive data such as API keys if you share the full URL.) ... It seems your provider currently support only Ethereum network, not BSC.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I used 'wss://${NETWORK}.infura.io/ws/v3/${PROJECT_ID}' on Ethereum. 
I don't know how to create WebSocket to get pending transactions on BSC. 
What provide link do I have to use on BSC? 
If you know about that, Please help me.

Comment: Infura only provides data for Ethereum and Filecoin. You need to find a provider that provides data for Binance Smart Chain.

Comment: yes. you are right. But I can't find that provider. Could you teach me what is that provider?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for https://getblock.io/nodes/bsc

Once you get an API key, you can use this websocket address:

```
wss://bsc.getblock.io/mainnet/?api_key=API_KEY
```

I just implemented it, and it seems to be working for me!

UPDATE:

I have had better success with this service:
https://www.quicknode.com

GetBlock worked for me, but would sometimes get a little out of sync with the network.

Comment: Honestly that helped me alot, but the details are very limited comparing pending transactions over completed transactions. Do you have an idea how I could get more into detail? I'm trying for over two weeks now.